# No module named 'lsb_release' after install Python 3.6.3 from source

Tags: python3

platform: ubuntu 17.04 server

The ubuntu 17.04 server installation includes python 2.7 and python 3.5.
I installed the Python 3.6.3 manually from source. However, `lsb_release -a` failed:

```
# lsb_release -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

But if I modify the first line of the file `lsb_release` from

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -Es
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5 -Es
```

it works again.

```
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Here are the module search path:

```
# python3.5
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:58:41) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>> import lsb_release
>>> exit()

# python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct 14 2017, 20:35:42) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>> import lsb_release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
>>> exit()
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I think you should probably just rm /usr/local/bin/python3, and use python3.6 explicitly if you want to use 3.6 for something.

Comment: Why are you installing Python 3.6 from source?

Comment: It looks like you set up a different Python installation as the default in your Ubuntu system. This is known to lead to a lot of trouble because of different module installation paths. What's the output of `readlink -f /usr/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3 --version`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752279/lsb-release-not-working-after-install-python-3-6-3-from-source

Answer (score 52):

**Solution:**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lsb_release.py
```

**Explain:**

We can see in `/usr/bin/lsb_release`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -Es

# lsb_release command for Debian
# (C) 2005-10 Chris Lawrence <lawrencc@debian.org>
#    This package is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation; version 2 dated June, 1991.
#    This package is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this package; if not, write to the Free Software
#    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
#    02110-1301 USA
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
import os
import re

import lsb_release
```

The key step is `import lsb_release`, but the problem is `Python 3.6` doesn't have this module.

So, **you must have overrided `python3` from `python3.5` to `python3.6`. That's why your `lsb_release` is broken.**

To verify it, we can see in `python3.6`:

```
➜  ~ python3.6 
Python 3.6.4 (default, Feb  6 2018, 16:57:12) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsb_release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

then in `python3.5`:

```
➜  ~ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsb_release
>>> lsb_release.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py'
```

where is this file:

```
➜  ~ ll /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jul   7  2016 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py -> ../../../share/pyshared/lsb_release.py
```

So, this module `lsb_release` exist in `python3.5` but not exist in `python3.6`. And We find it eventually!

Now let's fix it through add a link to the original `lsb_release.py` file!

It works for me!

Comment: I got another error after added a link to the original `lsb_release.py` `ImportError: cannot import name 'get_lsb_information'`

Comment: Is `pyshared` a folder for backwards compatibility? The `ln` solution seems like a hack for newer python versions on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest re-installing `lsb_release` via apt:

1. Open a terminal window
2. run `sudo apt install --reinstall --mark-auto lsb-release`