# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'

Tags: 20.04, python3, lsb-release

Platform: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

When I run the `lsb_release -a` command, I get this error.

```
# lsb_release -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

The first line of my file `/usr/bin/lsb_release` has this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -Es
```

This is closely related to the problem given in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965043/no-module-named-lsb-release-after-install-python-3-6-3-from-source). But the symnlink  proposed solution proposed there does not helps me. I tried creating both of these two symlinks.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lsb_release.py

sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lsb_release.py
```

Here are the module search paths (I have python3.9, 3.8 and 2.7 on my laptop):

```
# python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, Nov 23 2021, 15:27:38) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsb_release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
>>> exit()

# python3.8
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsb_release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
>>> exit()

# python2.7
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jul  1 2022, 12:27:04) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsb_release
>>> lsb_release.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lsb_release.py'
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 20.04 the python3 version should be 3.8.2-0ubuntu2. It works fine for me:

```
doug@s19:~/kernel/linux$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsb_release
>>> lsb_release.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py'
>>> exit()
doug@s19:~/kernel/linux$
```

and

```
doug@s19:~/kernel/linux$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped to clarify in identifying the file path location of `lsb_release.py` in the python3 folder. On further investigation I was able to see that the symlink of the python3/dist-package/lsb_relase.py file was broken. I deleted that file, and created a new symlink as follow `sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`